# Are there metamagic feats for martial manuevers?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, tome-of-battle

Is there any equivalent to a metamagic feats that can be applied to martial maneuvers. For example a maximized death in the dark would be amazing.

Answer (score 6):

#### There are no official feats of this sort

*Tome of Battle* has zero official support outside of *Tome of Battle* itself, and the closest the book comes to this are the tactical feats associated with each school (which really isn’t like this at all).

#### Homebrew has done it, several times.

For example, [this person](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showsinglepost.php?p=2481388&postcount=1) made some, and someone retorted with [this set](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showsinglepost.php?p=2484243&postcount=4), which he or she felt was a better execution of the concept. They’re not alone (and I can’t vouch for these particular ones), but the concept is out there if you look. Giant in the Playground, in particular, has a lot of quality *Tome of Battle*-based homebrew.

Answer (score 3):

### Nope

Or rather, I should say, not officially.

There's [this homebrew](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?162975-3-5-ToB-Metainitiation-feat-PEACH), which is copy-pasta'd metamagic feats turned into 'metainitiation' feats.

There's also [this homebrew discipline](http://www.minmaxboards.com/index.php?topic=1351.0), which is a bit better written and about boosting your other martial disciplines (kind of like Tae Kwon Do).

The only **official** similar thing is the *Empower Supernatural Ability* feat from Tome of Magic, as some few maneuvers are called out as being Su instead of Ex.